# jQuery: How to remove the last character from input pressing backspace?

Tags: jquery

I tried this code:

```
$(document).keyup((e)=>{
   var k = e.key
   if(e.keyCode == 8){
       console.log(e.keyCode)
       var d =$("#inp").val()
       $("#inp").remove(k+d)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `keydown` instead of `keyup`, and you have to cancel the original event (with `preventDefault()`) otherwise you will delete **2 characters**

```js
$(document).keydown((e)=>{       
   var k = e.key
   if(e.keyCode == 8){
       e.preventDefault();
       var d = $("#inp").val();
       $("#inp").val(d.slice(0,-1));
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" value='test text to delete'/>
```

If you use `keyup`, the event will already have been executed so you cannot cancel it anymore.

Comment: plese do yourself using Run code snippet and you can understand bacspace removed all characters no last

Comment: No, the snippet is ok, removing just the last character. perfect solution as many other here. I'm upvoting this answer

Answer (score 2):

This will do it. Check the snippet. Use `keydown` instead of `keyup`.

```js
$(document).keydown((e)=>{
    if(e.keyCode == 8){
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        e.preventDefault();
        var d = $("#inp").val();
        $("#inp").val(d.slice(0,-1))
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: plese do yourself using Run code snippet and you can understand bacspace removed all characters no last

Comment: No it doesn't. It only removes the last character for me.

Comment: For me too, just last character, code is ok... You probable are having a problem on your PC... but this answer are just removing the characters when the focus is on the input, not everywhere in the document, so the backspace is acting like the normal behavior, not needing any code

Comment: It wasn't a downvote, i just removed my upvote because i noticed the information I said in my coment above.

Comment: @CalvinNunes No, you can check that I am preventing the default behaviour of backspace with `e.preventDefault` and it is indeed using the script. If you remove the `e.preventDefault` then you can notice that it is removing 2 characters.

Comment: yeah, but it is not necessary, if you remove the entire code and focus on input, it will delete as normal behavior of backspace button... And apparently, the asker is trying to delete even if he's not focusing on the input, but anywhere in the doc

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `remove()` to remove characters, `remove()` is a jQuery function the remove the element node from the DOM.

To be able to remove the last char when you hit backspace anywhere in the `document`, you should use `val()` passing to it the last value slicing the last character, see the code below.

Also, using `keydown` is a better idea because if you keep holding the backspace button with `keyup`, it wont delete, it will delete just one character when you release the button.

And when you have focus on the input, if you didn't add `preventDefault();` it will delete 2 characters, because of the normal behavior of backspace + the deleted one from the function...

```js
$(document).keydown((e)=>{
   var k = e.key
   if(e.keyCode == 8){
      e.preventDefault();
       var d = $("#inp").val();
       $("#inp").val(d.slice(0,-1));
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" value='abcdefghj'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an slice after getting input value and save as new val in input:

```
$(document).keydown((e)=>{
    if(e.keyCode == 8){
        console.log(e.keyCode)
        var d = $("#inp").val();
        $("#inp").val(d.slice(0,-1))
    }
})
```

Comment: but if i do that they remove all characters